# How do I examine a fresh Windows 10 installation

Tags: certificates, hash, man-in-the-middle, windows-10

I suspect an unauthorized modification has been applied to a fresh new installation of Win 10 x64 and/or a PC running it by a person who knows me personally with the purpose of tracking my activity and faking web or file resources. Nothing valuable enough to employ an investigation assistance, but a good reason to improve technical skills.

So... What is the start point for the mission? Is there a security checklist one should go through to examine the system security?

The following is my non-professional thoughts on the subject, so please be kind. Also, I never used Windows 10 before as my primary OS, and could miss new APIs and policy changes.

First of all, I guess there should be a way to check whether system files were altered. Since the NTFS metadata could be easily edited, I suppose only hash checking would work, but as Microsoft baking their Fixes, Patches and Security Updates non-stop, one will need a script and a CRC DB.

From which it follows the Internet connection via this (hypothetical) DB is accessed should be independently checked. What seems to me even more realistic, if some kind of a proxy device is plugged between, even carefully examined installation could be compromised at any moment by replacing original files since Win 10 updates are (AFAIK) mandatory (I guess, implementing the scheme is not a big deal nowadays after Raspberry/Orange/You name it Pies were widely adopted). Is there a built-in server checking procedure in Windows 10 and if yes how reliable is it?

Then, certificate list should be validated and/or rolled back to its original state. (As far as I know, it could be done with the Security Policy, right?).

All the drivers (including legacy ones) should be validated as well. It would be nice to have a tool/script, checking signings. At least, for the drivers developed by Microsoft and not replaced with the ones bundled with the hardware (basically, motherboard).

Any remote connections should be prohibited, including new nix subsystem administration protocols. (How?)

All unnecessary automation tools (which ones?) should require manual approving at least at the first script running.

Any books/manuals/articles are welcome as well as general thoughts on the subject.

Comment: Can you list some more info? How did this person have access? Did you install this windows instance, or did it come pre-installed on the laptop? If I suggested factory default resetting, would you be capable of that. What is leading you to think this, is it technology based or suspicion of other persons character?

Comment: The person had uncontrolled physical access to the PC. The OS is preinstalled. I'm not sure what the 'factory default resetting' is, but it's my personal PC, with no data and I'm ready to perform any necessary steps. I have an evidence my current system was... well, for lack of a better word... _hacked_, but though I tried to make all the needed dumps, I'm not sure at the moment neither was it the person I think nor how far the person could go.

Comment: For system file integrity, `sfc /scannow` may help, unless sfc itself was tampered with

Comment: @Kat If you want to be safe, work with your laptop vendors customer service to "factory reset" your OS. They will know what you mean and there are pretty straightforward steps in 10 to do so. It is possible there is something more malicious on there which wouldn't be fixed by that, but unlikely unless the person with the laptop was very experienced. Here is an article on how to do this: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/reset-windows-10-pc  Make sure to "remove your files" and "clean the drives" in it's options. You said the laptop was clean, but warning:  -this will destroy all data-

Comment: CRC is absolutely no use here; it is not intended to be secure, and in fact is not secure at all (it is trivially forged by anyone who learned high school math).

Comment: When in doubt, wipe the machine clean and reload. It is far quicker and removes that nagging doubt of "did I get it".